# Replacing a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, replace, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

When I click on a certain link the server writes if I have done it by stating either true or false in a text file... 
Just like this:

```
{"needs_click":false,"has_clicked":false,"sites":[{"id":2134,"name":"testing","has_clicked":false,"click_url":"http://testing.com?siteid=5433"}]}
```

Now what I have done is uploaded a text file to my FTP already and changed all the false results into true like this:

```
    {"needs_click":true,"has_clicked":true,"sites":[{"id":2134,"name":"testing","has_clicked":true,"click_url":"http://testing.com?siteid=5433"}]}
```

Now in one of the JavaScript files attached to the source code there is the variable at the top directing to the text file I just need to know how to make my browser read the spoofed link I created instead of the original.
I need to change the variables:

```
var API_VERSION = 0.1;
var API_URL = "http://api.testwebsite.com/" + API_VERSION + "/";
```

To:

```
var API_VERSION = 0.1;
var API_URL = "http://api.testwebsite2.com/" + API_VERSION + "/";
```

So it reads the other text file stating all the true options instead of the original... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was impossible, at the time I was very new to programming and limitations on what I could and could not do.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a personal proxy to shape the query? Something like [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) could work. In any case you will need to get in between the browser and server to do this sort of thing.

Alternatively you could try to rewrite entire JavaScript (ie. remove the original from source before loading and inject your own with the url fixed, you might be able to get away with a `replace` on the original). I don't know how feasible this is, though, as I don't know internals of Greasemonkey well enough. But this might be something to explore.